# How to fix camera orientation when rotate device

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation

I use AVFoundation to record video.
I set video orientation: `[captureConnection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];`
When i record video, the output video looks like this: 
 
[image]
 
  
 
But then when I rotate my device it looks like this: 
 
[image]

I want my video always like the first image even when rotate device. What I have to do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be help

```
supportsVideoOrientation = NO
```

for more refer this [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureConnection/videoOrientation)

Answer (score 0):

Did u try this:

```
if ([captureConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
{
    [captureConnection setVideoOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
}
```

Comment: i meant checking if condition

Answer (score 0):

The pixel buffers captured by the camera are still laid out in the orientation in which they were captured. Many video players will not check for the preferred orientation metadata tag and will just play the file in the native pixel orientation. use AVCaptureSession it may be help you..
please check below link..

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1744/_index.html

Comment: My problem is not video's orientation. It is the orientation of object in video. Video is always portrait but objects in video are rotated follow device's orientation